# Why don't invited team members get emails to join my project in DevOps? Why can't they see my project?

Tags: azure-devops

I have just started trying to use Azure DevOps. Whenever I invite a new Team Member to join my project they do not get an email asking them to join. When they log into DevOps, they cannot see my project. I have a suspicion this is somehow related to Active Directory but I have no clue.

I have tried inviting work emails and gmails. I have check that the permissions allow notifications and project collaboration. The project shows the invited emails as part of the project.

Is it supposed to be this difficult to synch up your team?

Thanks!

Comment: Have they checked their SPAM folder? Perhaps the invites are there.

Comment: Yes we've checked that, thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to **Project settings**, click **Permissions** under **General**, click **Users** tab and select the new team member you added to your project. Make the **View project-level information** permission is set to allow for the new member.

[image]

I cannot reproduce the email not sending out issue. You can click the **3dots** at the most right of the User of the Users section in Organziation setting, and try resending invite a couple of more times.

[image]

You can check the Microsoft documents to [Add users to your organization or project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-organization-users?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Add users to a project or team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/add-users-team-project?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this now! Much appreciated.

Comment: Solved. TNX ALOT :)))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to update this to say that 'Resend invite' under Organization Settings > Users successfully sent the email to my users. Thank you for the great suggestion. No clue why they didn't send in the first place.

Comment: Hi @krylahh that is great it worked out, please kindly  [mark above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)